# How do I access and add a widget to MDGridLayout by ID : BOX in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How do I access and add a widget to `MDGridLayout` by ID : BOX in my case???

I tried to achieve the desired result in various ways, but it constantly gives an error, root does not see ID: BOX self.root.ids. ......

`print(self.test2.ids)` raises `AttributeError: 'TestApp' object has no attribute 'test2'`

While `print(self.root.ids)` returns

```
{'screen_manager': <WeakProxy to <kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager object at 0x00000221CA016580>>,
'toolbar': <WeakProxy to <kivymd.uix.toolbar.MDToolbar object at 0x00000221CA0B6E40>>,
'nav_drawer': <WeakProxy to <kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer object at 0x00000221CA133DD0>>}
```

test.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout


Builder.load_file('test2.kv')



class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDBoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return

TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>
    md_bg_color: 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 1

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                text: "Main Menu"

                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr1"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    icon: "menu-open"

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                text: "Test"

                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "test2"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    icon: "fire"


MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: 0.164, 0.164, 0.164, 1

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.width

        ScreenManager:

            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr1"

                MDBoxLayout:
                    cols: 1
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    md_bg_color: 0.235, 0.247, 0.254, 1



            Test2:


    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "SCUM INFO"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        md_bg_color: 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 1
        specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        right_action_items:
            [["magnify", lambda x: banner.show()], ["cog-outline", lambda x: app.set_screen("setting")]]


    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        ContentNavigationDrawer:
            screen_manager: screen_manager
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

test2.kv  (second screen)

```
<Test2@MDScreen>:

    name: "test2"

    MDBoxLayout:
        cols: 1
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDBoxLayout:
            cols: 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, .11

        MDBoxLayout:
            cols: 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, .89

            ScrollView:

                MDGridLayout:
                    id:box   # <---------------- ID ID ID ID
                    cols: 1
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '200dp'
                    padding: 5, 5, 5, 5
                    spacing: dp(15)
        # VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV DUPLICATE,DUPLICATE ---->
                    MDGridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        padding: 5, 5, 5, 5
                        md_bg_color: 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 1

                        spacing: dp(5)
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                            Line:
                                width: 1
                                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            cols: 1
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            size_hint: 1, .30
                            md_bg_color: 0.235, 0.247, 0.254, 1

                            MDRelativeLayout:
                                cols: 1
                                orientation: 'vertical'

    # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

                                FitImage:
                                    source: 'img.jpg'    # <----------

                                MDLabel:
                                    id: news_title
                                    text: "Some text"    #  <-------

    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                    text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
                                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                                    font_style: "H6"
                                    font_size: root.width/18
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to access the `ids` of the dynamic class `Test2`. You may achieve this as follows:

First refer it by creating its `id` in `kvlang` as,

```py
            Test2:
                id: test2
```

Now you should be able to access its inner ids as usual by `self.root.ids.test2.ids` (when done in `App`'s subclass i.e. here in `TestApp`)

Comment: Thanks! I thought I wouldn't find a solution anymore.